# Integrating a function with mod inside

Tags: integration

What I want to know is how can you integrate something like this:
$$
\int c\;mod\;x\;dx
$$
Where $c$ is some constant.

Comment: $c \mod x = c - x \lfloor \frac{c}{x} \rfloor$. Maybe that helps?

Comment: It might help to know the context in which you came across this integral.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was just curious, since I had never seen someone try solving such a thing.

Comment: Maybe that's because it makes no sense. $a\bmod c$ is generally only used when $c$ is a positive integer, while $\int\,dx$ generally refers to a real variable $x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Regarding you second commentary. That makes sense, and, one interesting thing is that if you put the integral on Wolfram|Alpha it says: "No result found in terms of standard mathematical functions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $a>0$ and $x>0$. Then the function $f_a(x)=a\pmod x$ can be defined piecewise as $f_a(x)=a$ for $x>a$, and $f_a(x)=a-nx$ for $\frac{a}{n+1}<x\le \frac{a}{n}$ for all integers $n\ge1$. We can write this compactly as an infinite sum. To do so, for integers $k\ge1$ let $\chi_k(s)$ be the characteristic function for the interval $I_k=(\tfrac{a}{k+1},\tfrac{a}{k}]$, meaning that $\chi_k(s)=0$ if the inequality $\frac{a}{n+1}<s\le \frac{a}{n}$ is false and $\chi_k(s)=1$ if said inequality is true. Additionally, let $\chi_0(s)$ be the characteristic function for the interval $I_0=(a,\infty)$, namely $\chi_0(s)=0$ iff $s\le a$ and $\chi_0(s)=1$ iff $s>a$.

We then have $$f_a(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a-kx)\chi_k(x).$$ 
Since all the intervals $I_k$ are disjoint, we have that if $\chi_i(x)=1$ for some $i$, then $\chi_j(x)=0$ for all $j\ne i$. Thus we need not worry about convergence of the sum.

Anyway, since at any $x$, each characteristic function is either a $0$ or a $1$, the integral of each characteristic function is either $0$ or $x$. More explicitly, $$\int \chi_k(x)dx=x\chi_k(x)+\text{constant}$$
for all $x$ and $k$. Similarly, we have $$\int x\chi_k(x)dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\chi_k(x)+\text{constant}.$$ This implies that 
$$\begin{align}
\int f_a(x)dx&=\int\sum_{k\ge0}(a-kx)\chi_k(x)dx\\
&=\sum_{k\ge0}\int(a-kx)\chi_k(x)dx\\
&=\sum_{k\ge0}\left[a\int\chi_k(x)dx-k\int x\chi_k(x)dx\right]\\
&=\sum_{k\ge0}\left[ax\chi_k(x)-\frac{k}{2}x^2\chi_k(x)\right]+\text{constant}\\
&=\frac{x}{2}\sum_{k\ge0}(2a-kx)\chi_k(x)+\text{constant}\\
&=\frac{x}2f_{2a}(x)+\text{constant}.
\end{align}$$